Short Film about a ballerina whose leg gets broken off
I have a vague memory of a single short film that I used to watch in the early 90's but I believe was made far earlier, perhaps the 50's. The short film was about a music box ballerina whose leg gets broken off. She's afraid that she is going to get thrown away with the broken toys, and so a soldier comes to her rescue to try and fix her leg.
The whole thing is stop-motion animation, not claymation, and there is very little talking throughout the whole thing. 
From my research it seems to be a variant of The Tin Soldier, but I can't seem to find the exact one.
This question has been raised before on this site: Stop-motion animation about a conductor with a large moustache, but there was no resolution. 
I realize I don't have a ton to go off of, but I figured it was worth a shot. Let me know if you have any ideas!
